# How Pytorch manage memory usage during training?

Tags: c++, memory, deep-learning, pytorch

It may be quite uninteresting topic, but I would like to ask this question that has been bothering me for a few month.
The project that I am working on involves implementing ResNet50 using CUDA/C++.
In the project, What annoys me the most is **memory usage during model training**.

When I compared the memory usage of *CUDA version ResNet50* and *Pytorch version ResNet50* during ImageNet training, I found that the *CUDA ResNet50* required about 7GB memory whereas the *Pytorch ResNet50* required only 4.3GB.
(I implemented relu inplace operation on both model. The training batch size is set to 32.)

This situtation has made me curious about **how Pytorch optimized its memory usage during training**, since it has shown that there is a room for further optimization in my implementation approach.

Here is the memory usage table:

| batch size | CUDA ResNet50 | Pytorch ResNet50 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1345MB | 1887MB |
| 2 | 1563MB | 1961MB |
| 4 | 1995MB | 2201MB |
| 8 | 2779MB | 2507MB |
| 16 | 4205MB | 3209MB |
| 32 | 6987MB | 4373MB |

First, I tried to explore the Pytorch Github repository to find out what kind of optimization methods are used at the CUDA/C++ level. However, it was too complex to get answer on my question.

Secondly, I checked the memory usage of intermediate (tensors between layers) values. I expected Pytorch to use float16 data type to reduce memory usage, but it wasn't.

Lastly, I tried to overlap input tensor and error tensor to reduce the memory usage to half, but I failed it.

**So, if you could provide me with any clues on what optimization methods Pytorch is using for memory-efficient model training (e.g. what methods are being applied at the autograd level), it would be a great help.**

P.S. I'm so sorry for that I can't show my source codes in this question because of license.